# How to define a class that features a generic parameter which extends a class that features a generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Consider the following case:

```java
public class PointCloud<T extends Point> { } 

public class PointCloud3d extends PointCloud<Point3d> { }
```

How would I write a class that takes a generic parameter `T` that is an extension of `PointCloud<T>`?

```java
public class PointCloudReader<T extends PointCloud> { 
    T read(String path);
}
```

or

```java
public class PointCloudReader<T extends PointCloud<?>> {
    T read(String path);
}
```

What's the difference between the two class definitions?

Comment: The correct way to do this is probably really `public class PointCloudReader<P extends Point, T extends PointCloud<P>>`

Comment: @LouisWasserman I actually think that is the answer I need.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I have a JNI project and working with inheritance and generics is a lot trickier than if I worked with Java alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither.

Use this:

```
public class PointCloudReader<P extends Point, T extends PointClound<P>> { 
    T read(String path);
}
```

---

This is no good because it use the *raw* type of `PointCloud`, and doesn't work anyway:

```
public class PointCloudReader<T extends PointCloud> { 
    T read(String path);
}
```

This is no good because it uses an *unknown* type of `PointCloud`, and doesn't work anyway:

```
public class PointCloudReader<T extends PointCloud<?>> {
    T read(String path);
}
```

Comment: Java cannot infer the bound of T from the superclass. You must restate it. It should be `class PointCloudReader<T extends Point> extends PointCloud<T> `: https://ideone.com/fNSkyi. I've taken the liberty to update it. If you disagree, let me know

Comment: Thanks, but don't you mean:

`public class PointCloudReader<T extends Point> { 
    PointCloud<T> read(String path);
}`

Comment: I'm using JNI, so generics are causing me a bit of trouble...

Comment: I think the comment of @LouisWasserman does it for me.

Comment: @VladAdrianMoglan I initially coded Louis' suggestion myself, but simplified it because it didn't seem necessary, I have put it back.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in first case you are using raw type which is not recommonded. In second case you are using wildcard which is more type safe.

for example,consider following code:

```
class Test <T extends ArrayList<?>>{
        void test(T t) {
            Object o=t.get(0);
            t.add("someStr"); //this line will be a compile error
        }
    }
```

If you are using `<T extends ArrayList>`, you won't get any compile error, but if you are using a wrong type ArrayList, a exception will be thrown ar runtime.
But if you use `<T extends ArrayList<?>`, there will be a compile error to warn you this line is not type safe.